# api-platform/admin complains about missing json files after install

Tags: symfony, webpack, admin, windows-subsystem-for-linux, api-platform.com

I have a functioning local install of api-platform on WSL:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/

However, after I ran `composer require api-platform/admin-pack`, I get the following 500 error at `/api`:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "/mnt/c/Users/user/symfony-project-path/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist.").

Last line of stack trace:

> in vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Bundle/Resources/views/SwaggerUi/index.html.twig (line 9)

Similarly at `/admin`, I get the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "/mnt/c/Users/user/symfony-project-path/public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist.").

Last line of stack trace:

> in templates/admin.html.twig (line 9)

Was the install script supposed to create the `./build` dir in `./public`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

***Environment***

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL)
- Symfony: v4.4

Comment: Seems something is trying to render (non-existant) templates. After composer install, did you update your frontend? Maybe using `yarn install`

Comment: @rkeet. The templates seems to be there. But the build dir is missing. I also ran `yarn add @api-platform/admin @babel/preset-react` as recommended but this did not help

Answer (score 1):

Try running `yarn watch` in your project directory.